# Use of ${ } in bash script if statement

Tags: bash, unix

New to bash scripting. In the beginning of a bash script a variable is initialized

```
silent_install=true
```

Then this variable is used in the following 2 ways in the script

```
if [ -z "$silent_install" ]; then
```

and

```
if [ -z ${silent_install} ]; then
```

What is the difference between the 2 usages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short: the second one is wrong.

Wrong because an unquoted variable will be subject of word splitting. If the variable contains spaces the test will fail.

The `{}` does not make a difference, you can use them or not, with or without quotes. However, generally I would advice to use them. Especially if you interpolate them like `"$foo_bar"`. What's the variable name here? `"${foo}_bar"` is much cleaner.

I would consequently use:

```
if [ -z "${silent_install}" ] ; then
```

Comment: @DevSolar You are right. (I didn't added that to my answer to keep it clear.) Since the extended test `[[ ]]` is a bash syntax feature rather than an external command (or command builtin), word splitting would not happen in that case.

Comment: @DevSolar Actually, there are some cases where double-quotes matter even in `[[ ]]`, such as on the right-hand side of a string comparison. IMO double-quoting everywhere is easier than trying to keep track of where it matters & where they're safe to leave off.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the double quotes making it ONE string. With the value `true` you will see no difference, but you will get into trouble when silent_install has special characters or spaces (`silent_install="I do not know"`).
Start getting used to `{}`. They do not matter here, but will matter when you have oher characters right after it (`$SILENT_INSTALLandmore`).
UPPERCASE characters are reserved for bash, so use `if [ -z "${silent_install}" ]`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the problems with word splitting the other answers point out, there's another problem with `[ -z ${silent_install} ]`. In one of the expected cases, where `silent_install` is unset or blank, the test command expands to `[ -z ]`. When the `[` command gets an expression with just a single argument, it tests that argument to see if it's non-blank. In this case, "-z" is non-blank, so the test returns true. This is the expected result, but that's just a coincidence; it's actually testing something very different from what the script author assumed it was.

The more serious variant of this scripting problem is the reverse test, `[ -n ${somevar} ]` (`-n` means "is not blank", the opposite of `-z`). Because `[ -n ]` actually tests whether `-n` is non-blank, it returns true, which is the opposite of what you'd expect.

The moral of the story is "double-quote your variable references!" It prevents all sorts of weird bugs and unexpected behavior.